# vba error message 13 IE.document

Tags: vba

I see that someone else has asked the same question but the answer didn`t help so I am having to raise it once more, 
I am running Windows 10 internet explorer 11,  64 bit 
I get error mismatch error 13 at last line

I have tried Dim IE As New InternetExplorer and Dim IE As New InternetExplorerMedium but still same error ..

any idea who I can get rid of the error please ? 
Thanks

```
Sub test()

Dim IE As Object ' InternetExplorer
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "http://stackoverflow.com/"

'wait while web page load

Set html = IE.document

end sub
```

Comment: What references have you added to VBA?

Comment: yes I have added Microsoft HTML Object Library and Microsoft Internet controls

Comment: Are you using 32-bit office, or 64-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using late binding instead for the HTMLDocument. Typically you don't need to assign the document to an object, you can just interact with it without assigning it to something else.

```
Sub test()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer ' Make sure you have Microsoft Internet Controls Reference added
    Dim html As Object ' Or you can use HtmlDocument as the type if Microsoft HTML Object Reference is added

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://stackoverflow.com/"
        While .busy Or .readystate <> 4
            Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
            DoEvents
        Wend
        Set html = .document
    End With
End Sub
```